# Check status of checkbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to create a function to see if a checkbox is  checked or not and if so, run `updateDocs()`.

I created the below but `const isChecked = document.querySelector('#isPaperless');` does not seem to be correct. How is this done?

```js
isChecked() {
  const isChecked = document.querySelector('#isPless');

  if (isChecked) {
    this.edocsService.updateEdocsStatus();
  }
}
```

```html
<label htmlFor="isPless">
    <input id="isPless" name="isPless" type="checkbox" /> I want to receive my policy documents 
</label>
```

Comment: You likely mean to do `if (document.getElementById("isPless").checked) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = document.getElementById('isPless');

function isChecked() {

    console.log("status : " + this.checked)

    if (this.checked) {
        
        this.edocsService.updateEdocsStatus();
    }
}

input.addEventListener("click", isChecked);
```

```html
<label htmlFor="isPless">
    <input id="isPless" name="isPless" type="checkbox" /> I want to receive my policy documents 
</label>
```